# AngularUI DatePicker - JavaScript - Date one day off when getting SQL Date format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angular-ui

I load in a SQL format date into a variable "2014-02-28" , but when I create a

```
new Date("2014-02-28");
```

the Date displayed in the input box is:

```
2014-02-27
```

In the AngularUI datepicker, the date is always one day off even if the value is correct in the model. Is there some way to remedy this?

Here is a Plunkr link which demonstrates the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/evBwPW0KO7cEWGp6vqtk?p=preview

I would like the model to be just the date in yyyy-MM-dd format, and for the date to be correct.

Comment: whoa! when I change my date format to yyyy/MM/dd it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Date format to

```
yyyy/MM/dd
```

fixed the problem

```
var date = new Date("2014-02-28"); // date loaded in SQL format
date.replace(new RegExp("-", 'g'),"/"); // now datepicker will show correct date
```

Comment: Should it be `date.toString().replace...`?

Answer (score -2):

date.tostring.replace(new RegExp("-", 'g'),"/");

Comment: `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined.`