# Angular datepicker using Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs

When we select a date from the angular Datepicker and my model is empty first time, then it selects one day back date.

If we assign current date first time in the model, then it works fine.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show your code.

Comment: please provide code snippet and please follow the stranded while asking a question on  stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226766/angular-ui-one-day-is-subtracted-from-date-in-ui-date) 
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105909/angularui-datepicker-javascript-date-one-day-off-when-getting-sql-date-forma)

It seems that in both, changing the date format seemed to fix the problem. 
Also, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment,
Please visit http://plnkr.co/edit/evBwPW0KO7cEWGp6vqtk?p=preview
and when you comment the $scope.loadedDate and $scope.dateFromAjaxCall in example.js file then try to run to run the program, you will get the error.
The issue I am facing is that it deduct one day from the selected date from the calendar.

Comment: Having `$scope.loadedDate and $scope.dateFromAjaxCall` commented or un-commented did not effect my ability to pick the correct date. Whatever I selected in the data picker was correctly displayed. Are you still having an issue?

Comment: This will always show the correct date in the textbox but when you bind the value in the expression like {{dateFromAjaxCall}} then it show one day back date and comment the   // $scope.loadedDate = "2014-02-28";
   //$scope.dateFromAjaxCall = "2014/02/28";
   //$scope.myDate = new Date($scope.dateFromAjaxCall); in the example.js file